# What are the first 3 digits of the product of the first 1000 fibonacci numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

> What are the first 3 digits of the product of the first 1000 Fibonacci numbers?

Could anyone give me hints on how to start this problem? I haven't done a problem like this before and I am curious on how to approach such a problem.

Comment: First three digits from left to right? From right to left?

Comment: From left to right I believe.

Comment: What do you mean, you believe? You are the one asking the question.

Comment: @Andres: Or perhaps just the one transmitting the question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott What question? I still don't know...

Comment: @Andres: The question *What are the first $3$ digits ... numbers*.

Comment: Brian would be right on "Or perhaps just the one transmitting the question"

Comment: @BrianM.Scott http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=airT-m9LcoY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Binet's formula gives us a useful approximation ($\tau=(1+\sqrt5)/2$)
$$
F_n\approx\frac{\tau^n}{\sqrt5}.
$$
For example with $n=8$ the r.h.s. is $21.00952$.

We have $F_1F_2\cdots F_7=3120$, so
$$
\begin{aligned}
\log(\prod_{i=1}^{1000}F_i)&\approx\log(3120)+\sum_{i=8}^{1000}(i\log\tau-\log\sqrt5)\\
&=\log(3120)+500472\log\tau-\frac{993}2\log5\\
&\approx 104248.9178386,
\end{aligned}
$$
so using the fractional part of that gives
$$
10^{0.9178386}\approx8.27635.
$$
Thus the answer is $827$ or something close to it. I skipped the estimation of the error. Note that the error to Binet's formula alternates and tends to zero, so it is not too difficult to estimate it.

Comment: The error in $F_8$ is approximately one part in 2000. Some of that will get cancelled by the error in $F_9$, but this gives us a reason to believe that the answer is correct up to 3 significant digits.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we have agreement that the sequence starts with: `{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...}`, then one can just compute it. Here is the product using *Mathematica*:

```
Product[Fibonacci[i], {i, 1, 1000}]
```

> 827363170408544049180720689718382309620058799258572848699373843 ... etc etc goes on for a few pages.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $F_n$ is very close to $\varphi^n/\sqrt{5}$, where $\varphi = \ldots$.
You should be able to use this approximation for $N < n \le 1000$ (for suitable $N$, hopefully not too big), and compute $F_1 \ldots F_N$ exactly.  It may be best to work with logarithms rather than with the product directly.